# Using datatables in angular 2

Tags: angular, datatables

I am trying to use DataTables in an angular 2 project. Please see my code below on how I implement it.

**.ts**

```
declare var $:any;
users: UserModel[];
public dataTable: DataTable;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
this.us.getUsers()
  .subscribe((data:any)=>{
    this.users = data;

    var table=$('#datatables').DataTable({
      "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
      responsive: true,
      language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
      }
   });
  });
  }
```

**.html**

```
<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>MiddleName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Email </th>
            <th>IsActivated </th>
            <th>DateAdded</th>
            <!-- <th class="text-right">{{ tableData1.headerRow[4] }}</th>
              <th class="text-right">{{ tableData1.headerRow[5] }}</th> -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
            <td class="text-center">{{user.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.MiddleName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
            <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.IsActivated}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can get the data and render it in the table but when I use the filter, all of the data goes away. When I remove the characters from the search box, I cannot get the data back. Even when I use the sorter arrow, I get the same issue. Can you please show me how to do this right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reproduced your problem on stackblitz. Seems like there is and issue with using `ngFor` in with jQuery datatable. I fixed this issue by providing `this.users` as data argument of the datatable along with columns and removing the `<tbody>` section from the html. As i did not have the service to get users, i created a  `users` array in the component and generated datatable for it. Please do as i did, and your datatable will work fine. Link: [Working Datatable Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxdbgi-xa4n9t?file=app%2Ftab-nav-bar-basic-example.html)

Comment: I have used your suggestion but still a no go. Please see my edit. Thank you.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOO MMMMMMUUUUCCCHHHHH!!! I have been trying to solve this for 3 days now!!

Comment: I have another question Sir. If you have time to answer it. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079061/adding-button-to-each-row-of-a-datatable-with-event-in-angular-2"